# How to split digits and letters in scala?

Tags: regex, scala

Waht would be an idiomatic way to split strings that may contain any combination of digits and letters into groups of digits and letters but keeping the order).

ex:

```
X45C -> X-45-C
5K -> 5-K
```

How would be an elegant way to implement that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex to the rescue!

```
val xs = List("X45C", "5K")
val ys = xs map {x => """\d+|\D+""".r.findAllIn(x).toList}

println(ys)
  /* List(List(X, 45, C), List(5, K)) */
```

If `\D` is the right choice depends on the actual input, consult the [pattern docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this may help:

```
"x12y 1y2 QW23ER"
    .replace(/([a-z])([0-9])/gi,"$1-$2")
    .replace(/([0-9])([a-z])/gi,"$1-$2");

// OUTPUT: "x-12-y 1-y-2 QW-23-ER"
```